# JavaScript prorate calculator, function called within function doesn't return same value

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple JS prorate calculator specific to my work needs. When I call `calculateProrate()` in the console, it returns the correct answer, but when I call it from within my `getFormData()` function, it returns a much higher and obviously wrong answer.

```js
function calculateProrate(a,b,c,d) {
  // a = added monthly cost of service
  // b = removed monthly cost of service
  // c = day of month service was changed
  // d = start of customer's billing cycle (same each month)
  return ((a + (b * -1)) / 30) * ((d + 30) - c);
}

function getFormData() {
  var addedCosts = document.getElementById('added-costs').value;
  var removedCosts = document.getElementById('removed-costs').value;
  var startDay = document.getElementById('start-day').value;
  var billingStart = document.getElementById('billing-start').value;
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
  answer.innerHTML = calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart);

  // for testing purposes
  console.log("Added costs: " + addedCosts);
  console.log("Removed costs: " + removedCosts);
  console.log("Start day: " + startDay);
  console.log("Billing start: " + billingStart);
  console.log("Prorate amount: " + calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart));
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getFormData);
```

```html
<h1>Prorate Calculator</h1>
<p>Added monthly costs: <input id="added-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Removed monthly costs: <input id="removed-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Day change starts: <input id="start-day" type="text"></p>
<p>Billing cycle start day: <input id="billing-start" type="text"></p>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p>Answer: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

For instance, when I run `calculateProrate(20,0,21,3)` in the console, it returns `8` which is right. But on the page and even in a `console.log` from within `getFormData()`, it returns `2060`. How did it reach that answer?

Edit: I am not using this in production. It is just for my personal use, to give *approximate* pro-rate amounts before making changes in our system, after which I can view actual amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your inputs are integers, you are doing math on strings.

```
> calculateProrate(20,0,21,3)
8
> calculateProrate("20","0","21","3")
2060
```

Try using the `Number` function, as in:

```
a = Number(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing math on input string not on a number. You can use function 'parseInt' to convert input string to int then everything will work

```js
function calculateProrate(a,b,c,d) {
  // a = added monthly cost of service
  // b = removed monthly cost of service
  // c = day of month service was changed
  // d = start of customer's billing cycle (same each month)
  return ((a + (b * -1)) / 30) * ((d + 30) - c);
}

function getFormData() {
  var addedCosts = parseInt(document.getElementById('added-costs').value);
  var removedCosts = parseInt(document.getElementById('removed-costs').value);
  var startDay = parseInt(document.getElementById('start-day').value);
  var billingStart = parseInt(document.getElementById('billing-start').value);
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
  answer.innerHTML = calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart);

  // for testing purposes
  console.log("Added costs: " + addedCosts);
  console.log("Removed costs: " + removedCosts);
  console.log("Start day: " + startDay);
  console.log("Billing start: " + billingStart);
  console.log("Prorate amount: " + calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart));
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getFormData);
```

```html
<h1>Prorate Calculator</h1>
<p>Added monthly costs: <input id="added-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Removed monthly costs: <input id="removed-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Day change starts: <input id="start-day" type="text"></p>
<p>Billing cycle start day: <input id="billing-start" type="text"></p>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p>Answer: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text fields are `Strings` not `Number` type. Use `parseInt` for every input.
[MDN Parseint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

**JSFiddle:**

```js
function calculateProrate(a,b,c,d) {
  // a = added monthly cost of service
  // b = removed monthly cost of service
  // c = day of month service was changed
  // d = start of customer's billing cycle (same each month)
  return ((parseInt(a,0) + (parseInt(b, 0) * -1)) / 30) * ((parseInt(d) + 30) - parseInt(c));
}

function getFormData() {
  var addedCosts = document.getElementById('added-costs').value;
  var removedCosts = document.getElementById('removed-costs').value;
  var startDay = document.getElementById('start-day').value;
  var billingStart = document.getElementById('billing-start').value;
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer');
  answer.innerHTML = calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart);

  // for testing purposes
  console.log("Added costs: " + addedCosts);
  console.log("Removed costs: " + removedCosts);
  console.log("Start day: " + startDay);
  console.log("Billing start: " + billingStart);
  console.log("Prorate amount: " + calculateProrate(addedCosts, removedCosts, startDay, billingStart));
}

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getFormData);
```

```html
<h1>Prorate Calculator</h1>
<p>Added monthly costs: <input id="added-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Removed monthly costs: <input id="removed-costs" type="text"></p>
<p>Day change starts: <input id="start-day" type="text"></p>
<p>Billing cycle start day: <input id="billing-start" type="text"></p>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p>Answer: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need two additional pluses:

```
((+a + (b * -1)) / 30) * ((+d + 30) - c);
```